# "[nested] failed to find nested object under path [steps]"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have mapped data into this schema:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/data?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d 
'{
   "settings":{
      "number_of_shards":"1",
      "number_of_replicas":"1"
   },
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "routines":{
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{
               "title":{
                  "type":"text"
               },
               "sources":{
                  "type":"keyword"
               },
               "flags":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "null_value":"NULL"
               },
               "steps":{
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{
                     "time":{
                        "type":"keyword"
                     },
                     "products":{
                        "type":"nested",
                        "properties":{
                           "name":{
                              "type":"text"
                           },
                           "link":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           },
                           "type":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           },
                           "ingredients":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           },
                           "flags":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Now, I am trying to search two fields `data.title` and `data.steps.products.name` with this query:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/data/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "steps",
                "query": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "products",
                    "query": {
                      "multi_match": {
                        "query": "XXX",
                        "fields": [
                          "name"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {"multi_match": {
                "query": "XXX",
                "fields": [
                  "data.title"
                ]
              }
            }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

It throws error that it failed to find path under step:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "query_shard_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to create query: [nested] failed to find nested object under path [steps]",
        "index_uuid" : "SjQgt4BHStC_APsMnZk8BQ",
        "index" : "data"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "data",
        "node" : "L1azdi09QxanYGnP-y0xbQ",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "query_shard_exception",
          "reason" : "failed to create query: [nested] failed to find nested object under path [steps]",
          "index_uuid" : "SjQgt4BHStC_APsMnZk8BQ",
          "index" : "data",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
            "reason" : "[nested] failed to find nested object under path [steps]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Could you help to find an error with mapping/query?

**UPDATE:**

My json data: https://jsonkeeper.com/b/PSVS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the Elastic documentation for [multi-level nested queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html#multi-level-nested-query-ex).

What you forgot in your query is the full path of the nested object in each sub-level nested query. (also, you used a `data` field not existing in the mapping, while you wanted to have `routines` instead)

So your query would look like

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/data/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "routines",
            "query": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "routines.steps",
                "query": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "routines.steps.products",
                    "query": {
                      "multi_match": {
                        "query": "XXX",
                        "fields": [
                          "routines.steps.products.name"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {"multi_match": {
                "query": "XXX",
                "fields": [
                  "routines.title"
                ]
              }
            }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Anyhow, please reconsider whether it is a good idea to have multi-level nested fields in the first place, as they have a significant impact on performance. E.g., would having an index for `routines`, maybe with a `data` identifier, make sense?

Edit: added the full path to the multi-matched field of the first should block

Comment: Thanks a lot @glenacota! For now it doesn't have to be the most performant but I will look into it!
I still have an issue with this query. It returns no hits... I've updated the question with json document data. Could you help me? Maybe I did wrong mapping?

Comment: hi, yes, your mapping is not matching your data. In your mapping, you defined `steps` as a sub-field of the `routines` root field, but in your data there's no `routines` field and `steps` is the root.

Comment: sorry, the file saved under the URL didn't save properly. Here is the good data: https://jsonkeeper.com/b/PSVS

Comment: try to add the full path to the (`routines.steps.products.`)`name` field of the multi_match query of the first should block